# Bezout's lemma in Euclidean Domains

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm wanting to show that given an ED $R$ whose identity is $1$, and two elements $a, b \in R$ whose gcd is a unit, that $\exists x, y \in R $ st $ax + by = 1$. Caveat-- I don't want to utilize the notion of a PID, or of ideals at all directly. Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: If it's a Euclidean domain, then you can use the Euclidean algorithm, and then run it backwards just as over $\mathbb{Z}$ to find the appropriate $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @rogerl Could you possibly demonstrate a bit, perhaps in an example ring like $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Can you use ideals *indirecty*? i.e. the set $\,S = \{ax + by\},\ x,y\in R\,$ is closed under addition, negation, and multiplication by elements of $R$, so by the division algorithm, a least element $\,u\,$ divides all other elements. Thus $\,u\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, u\,$ is a unit, by $\,a,b\,$ coprime. QED $\ $  If that way works for you, I can elaborate.

Comment: @BillDubuque That indeed does work. Please feel free to elaborate-- the only things I'm trying to assume are the axioms for the integers, and basic things we can derive from that -- i.e. the division algorithm for the integers, Bezout's Lemma for the integers, etc.

Comment: Are you avoiding ideals because you haven't yet studied them, or some other reason? I can answer better knowing that.

Comment: @BillDubuque I haven't studied them formally, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not yet studied ideals, I will give a proof eliminating the ideal-theoretic language, but still preserving the structural essence. Let $\,S\,$ be the set of all $\,R\!\!-\!\!$ linear combinations of $\,a,b,\,$ i.e. $\,S = \{ax+by\ :\ x,y\in R\,\}.\,$ We prove, by  Euclidean Division with Remainder, that any nonzero $\,d\in S\,$ having minimal Euclidean value $\,v(d)\,$ is a greatest commmon divisor of $\,a,b.\,$

The set $\,S$ enjoys the following arithmetical structure: it is closed under the operation of addition, and is closed under the operation of multiplication by any element $\,r\in R,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} (1)\  && \hat s\in S,\ s\in S\! &&\Rightarrow\,  s = ax\!+\!by,\ \hat s = a \hat  x\!+\!b\hat y\,\Rightarrow\, s\! +\! \hat s = a(x\!+\!\hat x) + b(y\!+\!\hat y)\,\Rightarrow\, s\!+\!\hat s\in S\\
 (2)\  &&r\in S,\ s\in S\! &&\Rightarrow\, s = ax\!+\!by\,\Rightarrow\, rs = a(rx)\! +\! b(ry)\,\Rightarrow\, rs\in S\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}\end{eqnarray}$$

As a consequence,  $\,S\,$ is further closed under the operation of remainder (or "mod"), since dividing $\,s\div t\,$ yields $\, s = q t + r\,$ so $\ r = s - qt\in S$ since $\,(-q)t\in S$ by $\,(2)\, $ so $\,s + (-q)t\in S$ by $\,(1).$

Choose $\,0\ne d\in S$ having minimal Euclidean value. Then $\,d\,$ divides every  $\,s\in S,\,$ for otherwise the remainder of $\,s\div d\,$ is a nonzero element of $\,S$ having Euclidean value smaller than $\,d.$

Therefore $\,a,b\in S\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid a,b,\,$ i.e. $\,d\,$ is a $\,\rm\color{#0a0}c$ommon  $\,\rm\color{#0a0}d$ivisor of $\,a,b,\,$ necessarily $\,\rm\color{#c00}g\!$reatest, since $\,c\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid ax\!+\!by=d,\,$ so $\,c\,$ has value  $\,v(c)\le v(d)\,$ by $\,c\mid d.\,$ Thus $\,d = {\rm\color{#c00}g\color{#0a0}{cd}}(a,b).\ \ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ Interpreted constructively, this yields the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500) for the gcd.

Alternatively one can give an inductive proof as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/714409/242) or [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/756412/242)