# Why is that minimum positive element in the ideals of linear combinations is the GCD of it's factors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

[image: Definition]

Why is that the smallest positive element in the ideals of the form $a_1\mathbb Z + a_2\mathbb Z+...$ is the greatest common divisor of the coefficients $a_1, a_2...$?

I have seen a proof of that minimum positive element divides all of other elements without remainder but i can't understand how it can be the greatest common divisor. I can understand that any element in the ideal will be a multiple of the common divisors of the coefficients since we can factorize them to be so, but i can't see why it is the GCD. I am looking for intuition.

Comment: If $d$ is the minimal element of $I$, you seem to be happy that every element of the ideal is a multiple of $d$. Similarly, since $d$ is in $I$, every multiple of $d$ lies in $I$. So the elements of $I$ are exactly the multiples of $d$, and so 

$$I = (\ldots, -3d,-2d,-d,0,d,2d,3d,\ldots).$$ 

But if this is true, then what is the GCD of the elements in $I$?

Comment: It follows that $d=a_1z_1+\ldots +a_kz_k$ for suitable $z_i\in\Bbb Z$. Each summand on the right is a multiple of the $\gcd$, hence so is the sum, i.e., so is $d$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/798537/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242).

Answer (score 1):

The GCD of the $a_i$s is a linear combination over $\mathbb{Z}$ of the $a_i$ from euclid GCD algorithm, hence $d\mathbb{Z}\subseteq I$, $I$ being your addition ideal $\sum_i a_i\mathbb{Z}$. Also, as $d\mid a_i\;\forall i$, we get $I\subseteq d\mathbb{Z}$. So, $I=d\mathbb{Z}$.

So, GCD is $d$, and it is the smallest linear combination as $d$ being generator of $I$ has to be the smallest element.