# Conceptual question about the strategy used in the following theorem: Every Ideal of $F[x]$ is Principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, proof-explanation

To refresh everyone, the following picture from Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" details the proof for the theorem that **Every Ideal of $F[x]$ is Principal**:

[image: Picture of proof]

This strategy is pretty common, so I have seen it plenty of times. However, my question arises from the fact that:

> **$\operatorname{deg}(0)$ is undefined**

i.e. the degree of the $0$ polynomial is undefined. As such, it almost feels like this proof is comparing oranges to apples...in the sense that it feels like it is saying:

*Well, if the $r(x)$ polynomial has this property (i.e. $\neq 0$), its degree is a number that would be contradictory...so, it must be this other thing, whose degree is 'undefined'*.

Is something that is undefined still "a number"? Or is it something that is entirely "non-number"? How exactly does one logically evaluate this? Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Another way of reframing this question is:

> How does one compare an assumption that describes a numerical property to an object that has an undefined numerical property? i.e. $b(x)$ is described as having some $n \in \mathbb Z$ degree that must be the smallest number...how am I supposed to compare an undefined number (i.e. $\operatorname{deg} (r(x)=0))$ to this $n$?

If I cannot make this comparison, how can I decide whether or not it is a contradiction?

Comment: You can take the second sentence of the proof to read "any *non-zero* polynomial of lowest degree in J."

Comment: The argument never uses $\deg 0$. Why do you believe it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is fine - it's meant (though not explicitly stated) that $b(x)$ has the lowest degree among *non-zero* polynomials, which avoids that issue at that point in the proof. The later part of the proof never references $\deg 0$ - note that it quotes the remainder theorem in the following sense:

> [We can] write
>   $$a(x)=b(x)q(x)+r(x)$$
>   where $r(x) = 0$ or $\deg r(x) < \deg b(x)$.

Observe that there are two alternatives: either $r(x)=0$ *or* we take its degree to be lesser than that of $b(x)$. It finds out that the second alternative is absurd, and thus concludes the first alternative. It's formally just "We know $A$ or $B$ is true and $B$ is not true. Therefore, $A$ is true."

Note that it's also somewhat common to say that $\deg 0 = -\infty$ to preserve various properties of degree and to make the remainder theorem unconditionally state $\deg r(x) < \deg b(x)$. Then we still want to choose $b(x)$ to have the lowest degree among non-zero polynomials, but when we find out that $\deg r(x) < \deg b(x)$, we immediately know that $r(x)$ is not a non-zero polynomial (i.e. $r(x) = 0$)

Comment: one question about defining $\operatorname{deg}0$ as $-\infty$. In such a case, can I re-think the statement '$b(x)$ has the lowest degree among non-zero polynomials' as '$b(x)$ has the property of smallest degree $\land \  b(x)\neq 0$'? Therefore, although the degree of $r(x)=0$ is less than the degree of $b(x)$, it is equal to the 0 polynomial and therefore does not exhibit the same "form" of $b(x)$... so does not violate anything?

Comment: @S.Cramer Your re-thinking is a bit different - formally, the property that $b$ has is "$b(x)$ is non-zero and for all non-zero $a(x)$ we have $\deg b(x) \leq \deg a(x)$" or, even more formally "$b(x)$ is non-zero and, for all polynomials $a$, we have $a(x) \neq 0$ implies $\deg b(x) \leq \deg a(x)$." There's no nebulous issue of "form" - zero was not included in the set over which we minimized, so $b$'s minimizing property does not apply to $0$ in any way. It's sort of like how $0$ being the smallest non-negative integer doesn't contradict that $-1$ is lesser in a bigger domain.

Answer (score 2):

The proof never uses $\deg 0.\,$ Below is an abstraction of the argument that may help clarify this, including a view as a prototypical **least counterexample (minimal criminal) descent**.

Say $\,f\in \bar J := J\backslash 0\,$ is $ $ *good* $ $ if $\,f\,$ divides every element of $\,\bar J\,$ (else say $\,f\,$ is $ $ *bad*, $ $ i.e. not good).

Division Algorithm $\Rightarrow$ bad $f$ are not minimal degree (by constructing a smaller degree $\,f'\in \bar J,\,$ i.e. the remainder $\,f' := g\bmod f,\,$ using $\,f\,$ bad $\,\Rightarrow\,f\nmid g\,$ for some $\,g\in\bar J).$

So a min degree $\,f\in \bar J$ must be good  (if it were bad the above descent would yield a smaller deg $\,f'\in J,\,$ contra minimality). Note min degree $f$ exist by $\Bbb N$ is [well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) (and $\bar J$ not empty).

**Summary** $ $ By $\Bbb N\,$ well-ordered, minimal degree elements exist; furthermore, by Euclidean remainder (mod) descent, bad elements are not minimal, thus a minimal element is good.

This method works generally - requiring only a descent on bads using a [well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order) set $N$ of "sizes", i.e. every nonempty subset of $N$ has a least element. $\,N = \Bbb N\,$ in the OP.

We can view the proof as a *descent* on bads (counterexamples), i.e. if all elements are bad, then choose $f\,$ to be a least degree bad ([minimal criminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)). As above, the division yields a smaller (degree) bad, contra minimality. So not all elements are bad, therefore a good element exists.

Or, equivalently, well-ordering implies that if we iterate our descent process to generate a descending chain of bads then the chain is *finite*, necessarily terminating at a good element, since, [equivalently,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation) well-ordering means there are no *infinite* descending chains.

This type of induction (descent) is ubiquitous in mathematics so it is well-worth the effort to master it early (in *simple* instances like this, since it will be more difficult to do so in more complex cases).

**Remark** $ $ The proof [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3289264/242) to any Euclidean domain, i.e. any domain enjoying division with smaller remainder. The key idea is that *ideals are closed under remainder (mod)*, therefore  the "least" $\,d\in I\,$ must divide every $\,i\in I,\,$ else $\,0\neq i\ {\rm mod}\ d\,$ is in $\,I\,$ and smaller than $\,d,\,$ contra minimality of $\,d.\,$ The descent in this proof can be interpreted constructively as computing a generator of $\,I\,$ by computing the gcd of its elements (by taking repeated remainders).

This method extends to PIDs: [(Dedekind-Hasse criterion)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221700/242)
a domain $\rm\,D\,$ is a PID iff given  $\rm\:0\neq a, b \in D,\:$
either $\rm\:a\:|\:b\:$ or else some D-linear combination $\rm\:a\,d+b\,c\:$ is "smaller" than $\rm\,a.\,$ Every PID admits such a size measure, viz. the number of prime factors (cf. prior link).

Comment: I guess the way that I was approaching it was that the claim about $b(x)$ was essentially an existence claim of the form "Within the set of all non-zero polynomials in the ideal $J$, there exists $b(x)$, which has the least order". So without inferring that the set was referencing "non-zero polynomials", it seemed to me that I absolutely needed to use $\operatorname{deg}(r(x)=0)$ in order to see if there existed a different polynomial that had a degree even lower than $b(x)$. But with the addition of the "non-zero" specification, I see that there is no need to make the comparison.

Comment: @S.Cramer No doubt it would have been clearer to make explicit that implicit assumption. Minor slips like that do occur in many textbooks so one needs to read with a critical eye. With practice it is easy to remedy them (often done  *subconsciously* after you've mastered the material).

Comment: as always, cheers and thanks for the supplementary explanations~~

Comment: after reading up on the infinite descent principle, i had a quick follow up question. How crucial to this proof is the fact that the "degree" of a polynomial is restricted to natural number $\mathbb N$ values? For example, if in "made-up-fictitious-math-world" we defined degree as being "any real number $\mathbb R$", then the infinite descent strategy would be inapplicable...correct? Because in such a scenario, sequences of decreasing elements CAN BE infinite, right?

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes, the "size measure" (here degree) needs to take values in a well-ordered set to ensure that the descending chains can't be infinite.

Comment: @S.Cramer I added a remark about how it works for any domain enjoying division with "smaller" remainder (i.e. a Euclidean division "algorithm"). It deserves to be better known that the same idea works for any PID (see the link in the Remark).