# Does every pair of non-zero elements of $Z[\sqrt{3}]$ has a gcd?

Tags: linear-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, unique-factorization-domains, euclidean-domain

I have a question as follows:

Does every pair of non-zero elements of $Z[\sqrt{3}]$ has a gcd?

Now, since $Z[\sqrt{3}]$ is a Euclidean domain as I saw a proof in one of the already answered questions on this site only, so it is a UFD. And in any UFD, any two non-zero elements have a gcd.
So, every pair of non-zero elements of $Z[\sqrt{3}]$  have a gcd.

Is my explanation correct? Can anyone kindly verify my answer?

Comment: Right, for a proof see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/UFD_is_GCD_Domain). But perhaps you meant $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, where this is not the case.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde No, I meant $Z[√3]$ only. Thanks for your verification.

Comment: Yes, a Euclidean domain is a gcd domain (i.e. all gcds exists). The proof is the same as in the classical proof in $\Bbb Z\!:\,$ any nonzero element $\, d\in  I = aR + bR\,$ of least Euclidean value is a gcd of $\,a,b,\,$ since it divides all elements $\,i\in I\,$ (else $\,0\neq i\bmod d\in I$ and its smaller than $d$, contra $d$ minimal). See the [Remark here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3511688/242) for more.

Comment: Further a domain is UFD $\iff$ is a a gcd domain where divisibility is well-founded, i.e. there are no infinite divisibility chains $\,\ldots  d_3\mid d_2\mid d_1$ (equivalently it satisfies ACCP = ascending chain condition on principal ideals).