# double check my steps to find multiplicative inverse?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

assume we want to find the multiplicative inverse for $117$ in $Z337$.

i know that in order to find the the multiplicative inverse we use Euclidean and Extended Euclidean algorithm.

**Eculidian:**

$337 = 2*117 + 103$

$117 = 1*103 + 14$

$103 = 7*14  + 5$

$14  = 2*5   + 4$

$5   = 1*4   + 1$

**Extended Euclidean:**

not going to include the whole solution because i am pretty sure of it, i get:

$1=25*337-72*117$

Extended Euclidean gives us that the inverse is $-72$. but how come a calculator says the inverse is $265$ and so do the teacher. do i need to do anything more ? usually i only need to do Euclidean and Extended Euclidean to find the inverse.

Comment: $-72\equiv 265\ (\textrm{ mod }337)$

Comment: ohh i see, is it wrong to say that $-72$ is the multiplicative inverse? is it enough to stop at $-72$ ?

Comment: If the final result is negative, then you need to add the order ($337$ in this case).

Comment: I fixed some typos in your question (you had $177$ vs. $117)\ \ $

Comment: ops, sorry it should be 117. Thanks !

Comment: @ barak manos, any rule that says that the final answer cant be negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either answer is correct since they are both congruent, i.e. $\,{\rm mod}\,\ 337\!:\ \color{#c00}{{-}72}\equiv 337-72\equiv 265.\ $ Below is the complete calculation by [a fractional form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm

${\rm mod}\ 337\!:\,\ \dfrac{0}{337} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{1}{117} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{-3}{\color{#0a0}{-14}} \overset{\large\frown}\equiv \dfrac{-23}5 \overset{\large\frown}\equiv\color{#c00}{\dfrac{-72} {1}}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\dfrac{0}0\,$ or, equivalently, in equational form

$\qquad\  \begin{array}{rrl} 
[\![1]\!]\ \!\!\!& 337\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ \ 0\\
[\![2]\!]\ \!\!\!& 117\,x\!\!\!&\equiv\ \ 1\\
[\![1]\!]-3[\![2]\!]=:[\![3]\!]\ \!\!\!& \color{#0a0}{{-}14}\,x\!\!\!&\equiv -3\\
[\![2]\!]+8[\![3]\!]=:[\![4]\!]\ \!\!\!& 5\,x\!\!\! &\equiv -23\\
[\![3]\!]+3[\![4]\!]=:[\![5]\!]\ \!\!\!&  \color{#c00}1\,   x\!\!\! &\equiv \color{#c00}{-72}
\end{array}$

**Remark** $\ $ This is essentially the [augmented matrix form of the extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242), optimized by omitting one column, then interpreting the linear congruences as modular fractions.

Allowing negative remainders (i.e. least *magnitude* reps) often simplifies calculations, e.g.$\,10^{n}\equiv (-1)^{n}\equiv \pm1\pmod{11}\ $ is used to calculate remainders mod $11$ via alternating digit sums (casting out elevens). I did so above: $\bmod 117\!:\  337 \equiv \color{#0a0}{{-}14}\ ({\rm vs.}\ 103\,$ in your calculation). Using the smaller magnitude residue $\,-14\,$ simplifies subsequent calculations (it eliminates one step from your calculations, but generally such choices save many steps in longer calculations).

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2146004/242) for another worked example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i wonder if its mathematically correct to say that $-72$ is the multiplicative inverse? is it ok if the multiplicative inverse is negative ?

Comment: In@pabloBar $\ 117^{-1}\equiv -72\pmod{337}\,$ is correct, but $\,{ -}72  = (117^{-1}\bmod 337)\,$ is not correct. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: how would you translate these expressions in words?, sorry a bit bad when it comes the math expressions.

Comment: @pabloBar $\ a\equiv b\pmod n\,$ means $\,n\,$ divides $\,a-b,\,$ but $\, a = (b\bmod n)\,$ means the same *plus* $\, 0\le a < n,\,$ i.e. $\,a\,$ is the least nonnegative integer $\equiv b\pmod n,\, $ i.e. the remainder left on dividing $\,b\,$ by $\,n.$ $\ \ $

Comment: on exam i would do the calculations above and then state with the exact words that "the multiplicative is $-72$", would my statement be correct in this case ?

Comment: @pabloBar It depends on what was asked. If the answer $\,k\,$ is expected to be in normal form, i.e. $\, 0 \le k < n = $ modulus, then you need to shift it into this range. It's similar to asking if $\, 2/4\,$ is a correct answer for a problem with fractions, i.e does the teacher expect that  you normalize fractions to lowest terms?  i.e. reduce $\, 2/4 = 1/2.\ $

Comment: alright sounds good, the question only asked to find the inverse with no conditions on in which range the answer should be, so i guess my answer should be fine.

Comment: @pabloBar Probably so. I added a remark about this in the answer.

Comment: exellent answer mate, i marked your post as the answer. And sorry dont have enough reputation to upvote it but its totally worth +1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49931/discussion-between-pablobar-and-bill-dubuque).

Comment: if possible, do you have a link where it shows a multiplicative inverse can be negative? , just so i can backup myself when arguing with the teacher

Comment: @pabloBar Why don't you simply use the least positive rep to avoid any issues?  You can probably find examples in textbooks if you look at computations using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which typically involves computing inverses.