# Number of $n \to p \bmod n$ before getting to 0

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, programming

There isn't much background context, but is there any estimations on how many iterations of $n \to p\% n$ are needed before $n$ becomes 0? Percentage sign is modulo. ($p$ is fixed, prime in my context but not sure if it matters).

For example, when $p=10^9+7$, the maximum number of iterations needed is $50$. When $p=998244353$ (a common prime in competitive programming) the number of iterations is $45$. I don't see any proof that it requires approximately $\log p$, but it seems like so.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Also just to add, there probably isn't a closed form? So some approximate would be enough (upper bound or sth)

Comment: What is the start value of $n$ ?

Comment: @Peter Any value between 0-(p-1), and I want the maximum number of iterations. (if n>p it will end in two steps right haha)

Comment: This is close to but not quite an algorithm for computing the continued fraction expansion of $\frac{p}{a}$ (where $a$ is the initial value); the continued fraction computation ends after something like $\log_{\phi}(p \sqrt{5})$ steps which roughly matches up with the numbers you gave, but it doesn't actually quite match up to the continued fraction algorithm unfortunately.

Comment: Ah I see, as we can think of continued fraction as $(a,b)\to (b,a\% b)$, whereas here is $(a,b)\to (a,a\% b)$.(?) I'll try and see if that helps

Comment: Why is 998244353 a common prime in competitive programming? I mean, it’s close to a power of 10, but not *that* close- surely there are primes closer to $10^9$.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp 119x2^24+1 useful for numeric theoretical transformation (NTT)

Comment: @Qiaochu Actually it's the descent step of [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3130465/242) for computing modular inferences.

Comment: @BillDubuque this question actually comes from a recursive relation to find a modulo inverse, which is what your links algorithm describes. Is there any upper bound on number of iterations before it ends?

Comment: Hint: If you used a least magnitude residue system then each step decreases $n$ by at least a factor of $2\ \ $

Comment: @GarethMa Are you interested in the worst case (an upper bound that holds always) or the average case (the approximate value) ?

Comment: @Peter Both are fine and interesting for my purpose. Also, this is the source of the discussion (quite a lot of code): https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/83075

Comment: @GarethMa If you want, I can write a pari/gp-routine, but I have no idea for an efficient approach, it will take long for large $p$.

Comment: If you use a least magnitude residue system as @BillDubuque suggested, then you easily get an $O(\log p)$ bound. But if you're using a least nonegative residue system, the algorithm generally takes more steps ($p = 419$ gives e.g. $7 \to 6\to 5\to 4 \to 3 \to 2 \to 1 \to 0$ against $7 \to -1 \to 0$). I still expect an $O(\log p)$ bound, but I don't (yet?) see how to prove it.

Comment: @DanielFischer Precisely what do you mean by "generally" above?

Comment: @BillDubuque That there are many pairs $(n,p)$ for which the number of iterations needed to reach $0$ is larger when $p \mathbin{\%} n$ denotes the least nonnegative residue than if it denotes the least magnitude residue. Not "generally" as in "always".

Comment: @DanielFischer what does the arrow mean ? "Approaches", right ?

Comment: @Spectre No, it means one iteration. So for example say p=13 and $n$ starts at 5, then it'll go like $n=5 \to 13\%5=3 \to 13\%3=1 \to 13\%1=0$

Comment: @DanielFischer oh... so $n$ is updated every time... Thanks !

Comment: @GarethMa is $p$ prime ?

Comment: @Spectre for my purpose, yes.

Comment: @GarethMa I have put up a post here regarding it, but I didn't assume that it is prime, so as to look at the problem from a wider view.

Comment: @GarethMa, and is $n$ random ?

Comment: No restrictions than $0 < n < (p - 1)$, right ?

Comment: @Spectre yes. I am mainly interested in average and worst case performance (=number of iterations) for all input of n, but any progress would be great

Comment: @GarethMa thanks for the details..

Comment: @GarethMa a beautiful solution has arrived !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us remove the constraint that $p$ is a prime number. Given a strictly decreasing sequence $1=a_0 < a_1 < \ldots < a_k$ and consider the set

$$ S(\textbf{a}) := \{p: p \equiv a_j \pmod{a_{j+1}} \ \ \forall j = 0 \ldots k-1\} $$

This is exactly the set of numbers that will produce the sequence $\textbf{a}$ during this process. Note that this set is stable for shifting by $\text{lcm }\{ a_1, \ldots, a_k\}$, and that the set of solutions is determined by applying the chinese remainder theorem.

We will consider two particular sequences to get the following result:
(1) there exist arbitrarily large (prime) numbers that ends in $2$ iterations;
(2) there exist arbitrarily large numbers that ends in at least (about) $(\log p) /2 $ iterations.

For the first just consider the sequence $3>1$ and take a (prime) number $p\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

The second is more interesting. Consider the sequence $k > \ldots > 1$. This means that we have $p$ such that $p\equiv  m-1 \equiv  -1 \pmod{m}$ for all $m\le k$. Solutions of this system are exactly numbers that are $\equiv -1$ modulo $L_k:= \text{lcm}\{1, \ldots, k\}$. The smallest such positive number is exactly $L_k -1$. We can give an estimate of $\log L_k$ as starting from the equation

$$ L_k = \prod_{p \le k} p^{[\log k/\log p]}$$

Indeed, any prime will appear with the maximum exponent it can appear with. Taking the logarithm we get

$$ \log L_k = \sum_{p\le k} (\log p) [\log_p k] \le \sum_{p \le k} (\log p) (\log_p k +1) $$
$$ = \sum_{p\le k} \log k + \log p \le \sum_{p\le k} 2 \log k \approx (2 \log k) \frac{k}{\log k} = 2k $$

Using the prime counting theorem $|\{p\le k\}| \approx k/\log k$. Recall that $k$ is the number of iterations relative to the input number $p=L_k-1$. Thus we get
$$(
 \log p )/2 \approx ( \log L_k)/2 < k$$

Giving the desired solution.

Comment: Nice work, sir ! (+1)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't check the site. Thank you for your solution, I might need a bit more time to sit down and work through it, but thank you for your effort! I will accept hopefully soon, when I understand it <3

Comment: Thank you! Feel free to ask if you need clarifications :)

Comment: I reviewed the calculations and I was wrong in some details. Fortunately, this resulted in a better estimate :) I think now it should be easier to read

Answer (score 0):

Here's a semi-logarithmic plot of the maximum number of iterations required for a given $p$, with $p$ ranging from 5 to 5000, checking all $2 \le n < p-1$. Both the best & worst cases do seem to be growing logarithmically.

[image: max iterations plot]

And here's a plot of the mean number of iterations, for $1 \le n < p$.

[image: mean iterations plot]

These plots were produced using Sage / Python. You can play with an online interactive version [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFkMFqwzAMhu95ClEY2Cwb7aCXQWBPMHovJXipk6i1JWM729jYu892ypbRw_6brO-X5L_3bAGj9pHZBEDr2EfoeKJYVUfdg2F2rVXvwsnHCpI61Y0aGvj8KmXPHgiQwCsatHiowd1tLmiWTSj9VJnGTJcNYglmUYId3CwMWdgDcQT6y2a9eK3OV2yZn6-8NiDcNnNvT4d_xs2YPaSbsDx6HSdPkMMovftXZSYdhJRV9YSUQlRdLKFZhSRGbLbr9eWHLoY0Zy9cvUxUlkDcb3zbGkaU82W7ZDAYYusMxzZoi4aH5IohZcxpX8AP3WxlgcPIb2JXQ8TuHBrxzKRr2MgaBo9Hg6RDs7LqxH4lvwErGoZs&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) (the script is actually encoded in the URL, not stored on the server). If you set the 'hi' parameter too high, the server will probably time out.