# Finding $589x \equiv 209 \pmod {817}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I did this

[image]

Apparently this is wrong because the right answer is $17+43t$ for $0 \le t \le 18$. What went wrong? I know this is supposed to have 19 solutions but what I got was $-198 \pmod {817} + 43t$ and -198 mod 817 isn't 17.

Comment: $-198\equiv17\pmod{43}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why 43?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm just confused because usually it's mod (given mod). I get more or less why it's mod 43 but idk, it's not very intuitive.

Comment: $\gcd(589,817)=19$ and $817/19=43$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing really went wrong.

You got $589(-198+43t)\equiv209\bmod817$.

By the [mod distribution law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883921/if-ac%e2%89%a1bc-mod-m-and-gcdc-m-d-show-that-a%e2%89%a1b-mod-fracmd), this is equivalent $(\div19)$ to $31(-198+43t)\equiv11\bmod43$.

So $x\equiv-198 \equiv17\bmod43$.

So $x\equiv17+43t\bmod 817$.

---

You could have noted from the beginning that $589, 209, $ and $817$ are all multiples of $19$, so

$589x \equiv 209 \pmod {817}\iff31x\equiv11\pmod{43}.$

This can be solved using the Bezout identity $13\times43-18\times31=1$:

$x\equiv-18\times11=-198\equiv17\pmod{43}$,

so $x\equiv 17, 60, 103, 146, 189, 232, 275, 318, 361, 404, 447, 490, 533, 576, 619, 662, 705, 748, $

or $791\bmod 817$.

Comment: Why do I have to use this though and why can't I leave the answer as it is? It's still correct.

Comment: You could leave it

Comment: I think I get it, I was supposed to divide $589 \equiv 209 \pmod{817}$ by 19, which is gcd(817,589) to simplify things so I would have to work with big numbers. Then I was supposed to solve normally for $31x \equiv 11 \pmod{43}$, which gives me $1 = 43(13+31t)+31(-198-43t)$, multiply everything by 11, which gives me $11 = 43(143+31t)+31(-198-43t)$. Then do -198 mod 43, which is 17, and my answer is 17-43t for $0 \le t \le 18$. I suppose I was just missing the simplification.

Comment: How do you propose to "note" that $\,19\mid 209,589\,$ without computing their gcd?

Comment: @Silence No, you're not supposed to divide  by $19$ from the *beginning* because in general you cannot know that common factor without computing the gcd, which is what you did by using the euclidean algorithm. *After* you know the gcd then you can cancel it. Generally $\ ax\equiv b\pmod{n}$ is solvable $\iff d:=\gcd(a,n)\mid b,\,$ and if so then the general solution is $\, x\equiv (b/d)/(a/d)\pmod{n/d},\,$ i.e. cancel $d$ *everywhere*, e.g. see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242)

Comment: The fractional extended euclidean algorithm described in the prior link is much simpler, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2054339/242) and [here for many more examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=user%3a242%20fractional%20extended%20euclidean%20frown).

Comment: @BillDubuque:  my first step was to factor $817$

Comment: @J.W.T How did you do that? At OP: Generally factoring it is *much* more difficult than computing gcds (though in some special cases we may recognize "obvious" factors). So -  unless you can *very quickly* see a common factor -  usually it's best to go straight to an (extended) gcd calculation.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  I did that by trial division

Comment: @SilenceOnTheWire I added an answer showing the calculation using modular fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct since $\bmod 43\!:\ x \equiv -198 \equiv 5(43)-198\equiv \,\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\!\!17}$

An easier way [(*fractional* extended Euclidean algorithm)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242), first calculating $\,\gcd(817,589)\!=\!\color{#c00}{19}\,$ in parallel, and second assuming the gcd known & cancelling it out, working $\bmod 43 = {817}/\color{#c00}{19}$.

${\rm mod}\,\ 817\!:\,\ 
\dfrac{0}{817}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv
\dfrac{209}{589}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv
\color{90f}{\dfrac{-209}{228}}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv
\color{#90f}{\dfrac{19}{-95}}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv
\color{#0a0}{\dfrac{-171}{38}}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv
\color{#c00}{\dfrac{-323}{-19}}\overset{\large\frown}\equiv
\dfrac{0}0$

${\rm mod}\ \ \,43\!:\ \ \ \ 
\dfrac{0}{43}\,\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\ 
\dfrac{11}{31}\ \overset{\large\frown}\equiv\ 
\color{90f}{\dfrac{-11}{12}}\ \overset{\large\frown}\equiv\
\color{#90f}{\dfrac{1}{-5}}\ \overset{\large\frown}\equiv\ \ 
\color{#0a0}{\dfrac{-9}{2}}\ \,\overset{\large\frown}\equiv\ 
\color{#c00}{\dfrac{-17}{-1}}\, \overset{\large\frown}\equiv\ 
\dfrac{0}0$

$\begin{array}{rl}
\qquad\ {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ \ \bmod 43\!:\qquad\  [\![1]\!]  &\ 43\, x\,\equiv\ \ \  0\    \\
[\![2]\!]  &\ \color{c00}{31\,x\, \equiv\ \ \ 11}\!\!\!\\
[\![1]\!]\:\!-\:\!1\,[\![2]\!] \rightarrow [\![3]\!] &\    \color{90f}{12\,x\, \equiv {-}11}\   \\
[\![2]\!]\:\!-\:\!\color{1orange}3\,[\![3]\!] \rightarrow [\![4]\!] &   \color{#90f}{{-}5\,x\, \equiv\ \ \ 1}\ \\
[\![3]\!]\:\!+\:\!\color{}2\,[\![4]\!] \rightarrow [\![5]\!] &\:\! \ \ \, \color{#0a0}{2\,x\, \equiv {-}9}\  \\
[\![4]\!]\:\!+\:\!\color{1orange}2\,[\![5]\!] \rightarrow [\![6]\!] &   \color{#c00}{{-}1\,x\, \equiv {-}17}\ \\
[\![5]\!]\:\!+\:\!\color{1orange}2\,[\![6]\!] \rightarrow [\![7]\!] & \ \ \:  \color{90f}{0\,x\, \equiv\ \ \ 0}\
\end{array}$

$\begin{align}{\rm Therefore}\ \ \  x\equiv {\color{#c00}{\dfrac{-323}{-19}}\!\!\!\pmod{817}}&\equiv \,\color{#c00}{17}\!\!\!\pmod{\!43},\ \ {\rm by\ cancelling}\ \ 19\\ &\equiv\, 17+43\,k\!\!\pmod{\!817},\ \ 0\le k < 19\\[0.5em] 
&\equiv \{17,\, 60,\, 103,\ldots, 705,748,791\}\!\!\pmod{\!817}\end{align} $

**Remark** $ $ Normally the equations under the fractions are omitted after one masters the algorithm, but I include them since they are instructive when learning it. Notice the fractions in the $\bmod 817\,$ Euclidean sequence are the scalings by $19$ of those in the $\!\bmod 43$ sequence: $\,a/b\to (19a)/(19b)$.