# find integers n m such that

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

find integers m and n such that gcd(258,180 ) = 258m + 180n

so far I have

258 = (1) 258 + (0) 180

180 = (0) 258 + (1) 180

78 =  (1) 258 - (1) 180

-54 = (1)180 - 3(78)

however, im abit stuck once I get to this point

Comment: You have to use [euclidean algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qym5D5bhoQs) to write gcd as linear combination.

Comment: I assume you meant $258$ when you typed $250$

Comment: I added an answer showing how to complete yoru calculation. This is much easier (and less error prone) than the *backward* methods in the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to but it's a good idea to avoid negative values.

$258 = 1*180 + 78$

$180 = 2*78  + 24$

$78 =  3*24 + 6$

$24 = 4*6 + NOTHING$

So that is as far we can go.  $\gcd(180,258) = 6$--  as $6|180$ and $6|258$ but nothing larger than $6$ divides both.

So we want $258m + 180n = 6$

And we have $6 = 78 -3*24$.

But $24 = 180 - 2*78$ so $6 = 78 -3(180 - 2*78)$.

And $78 = 258 - 180$.

So $6= (258-180) - 3(180 - 2*(258-180))$.

And that's it.

$6 = (258 - 180) - (3*180 -6(258 - 180))=$

$258 - 180 - 3*180 + 6(258 -180) =$

$258 - 180 -3*180 + 6*258 - 6*180 =$

$7*258 - 10*180$

So $m=7$ and $n=-10$.

.......

Oh I forget to mention that $m=7$ and $n=-10$ are not that only such integers of course.

$180 = 6*30$ and $258 = 6*43$

And $6=258*7 +180*(-10) =$

$258*7 + 180*(-10) + 0 =$

$258*7 + 180*(-10) + (M - M)=$  (for any $M$)

$258*7 + 180*(-10) + (k*6*30*43 - k*6*30*43)=$ (for any integer $k$)

$[258*7 + k*6*30*43] + [180*(-10) - k*6*30*43] = $

$[258*7+258*30k] + [-180*10 - 180*43k] = $

$258(7+30k) + 180(-10 - 43k)$

So $m = 7+30k$ and $n= -10 -43k$ for any integer $k$ will be a solution so there are infinitely many solutions.

Including $m = -23$ and $n=33$

But $m=7$ and $n=-10$ are the "smallest" solution (where $|m-n|$ is least)

Comment: I don't understand why you promote the *backward* version when the *forward* version is generally much easier and less error prone (and here it is the approach the OP asks about). Get on the bandwagon!

Comment: I'm not *promoting*. I'm just describing what the answer is and how you can derive a method of doing on your own if you don't know a method.

Answer (score 1):

You started out correctly applying the [*forward* extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually/85841?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#85841)  but went astray at  the 4th line by not using the (positive) remainder. Instead,  it should proceed from there as

$$\begin{align} r_4 = 24\, &= \ \ {-}2(258)\ +\ 3(180)\ \ \,[=\, r_2 - 2\, r_3]\\[.2em]
{\rm Bezout\ Identity}\ \rightarrow\ r_5\, =\ 6\, &= \ \ \ \ \ 7 (258) -10 (180)\ \ \,[=\, r_3 - 3\, r_4] \\[.2em]
 r_6\, =\  0\, &= -30(258)+43(180)\ \ \,[=\, r_4 - 4\, r_5] \end{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

**Remark** $ $ You could get back on track by adding your final two equations, but it is usually more efficient to choose $\,q_i\,$ to obtain the *least* (positive)  value $\, r_{i+1} = r_{i-1} - q_i r_i,\,$ which occurs when $\,q_i$ is the quotient $r_{i-1}\div r_i,\,$ so $\,r_{i+1} = r_{i-1}\bmod r_i\,$ as in the Euclidean algorithm. Any value of $\,q_i\,$ will preserve the gcd since $\,(r_i,r_{i+1}) = (r_i,\, r_{i-1} - q_i r_i)= (r_i,r_{i-1})\,$ but the goal is to generate a minimal *decreasing* (remainder) sequence $\,r_i\,$ in order to optimize the search for the gcd (= *least* positive linear combination of gcd arguments). In fact generally we can eliminate half of the computations by using *least magnitude* (signed) remainders, e.g. [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/615235/242)

Answer (score 0):

[Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm):

$258=180+78$

$180=2\times78+24$

$78=3\times24+6$

$24=4\times6$

Therefore,

$78-3\times24=6$

$78-3\times(180-2\times78)=6$

$7\times78-3\times180=6$

$7\times(258-180)-3\times180=6$

$7\times258-10\times180=6$

Comment: Please see my comment on fleablood's answer.