# Prove this statement: If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then for any $x$ that is an integer, there are integers such that $x = ma + nb$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So I know when two integers are relatively prime, their greatest common divisor is $1$ and it can we be written as a linear combination as: $1 = am + nb.$ But how would I prove the existence of these integers a and b?

Comment: use the extended Euclidean algorithm

Comment: Is that working backwards from the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3425420/find-integers-n-m-such-that)

Comment: Scale the Bezout identity $\,m a + n b = 1\,$ by $\,x\,$ to get $\, (xm) a + (xn) b = x\ \ $